# How to factorise N: Euler's Factoring Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I encountered a math problem that a method about how to factorize
$$N=ma^{2}+nb^{2}=mc^{2}+nd^{2}$$ into $$N=(N,ad-bc)\cdot \frac{N}{(N,ad-bc)}$$
This method is from a paper 'A Note on Euler's Factoring Problem
https://www.jstor.org/stable/40391253?seq=3
Theorem 2 states:
Let N be an odd integer, expressed in two different ways as
\begin{equation}
N=ma^{2}+nb^{2}=mc^{2}+nd^{2}\tag{6}
\end{equation}
where a,b,c,d,m,n $\in\mathbb{Z^{+}}$, b<d, and the greatest common divisor of (ma,nb) and (mc,nd) is 1. Then
\begin{equation}
N=(N,ad-bc)\cdot \frac{N}{(N,ad-bc)}\tag{7}
\end{equation}
I'm having trouble understanding and deriving the identities
\begin{equation}
(d^{2}-b^{2})N=m(ad-bc)(ad+bc)\tag{8}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
N^{2}=(mac-nbd)^{2}+mn(ad+bc)^{2}\tag{9}
\end{equation}
from
\begin{equation}
N=ma^{2}+nb^{2}=mc^{2}+nd^{2}\tag{6}
\end{equation}
Despite several hours of effort, I've been unable to successfully cancel out or multiply by N to complete the process. I'd greatly appreciate any advice on how to proceed with this derivation. Furthermore, I would like some suggestions on improving my skills in mathematical deduction to better tackle such problems in the future.

Comment: Here's a suggestion for deriving (8) from (6). You can see that there's no $n$ in (8) so you'll have to eliminate it from the two equations (6).  To do that, you'll have to multiply each of the two equations in (6) by a different factor so that the coefficient of $n$ is the same in each one and subtract the results.

Comment: @MatthewTowers 's hint is good. In general, while mathematical ability is something that takes time and practice to improve, I would advice against spending several hours doing algebraic manipulations on equations. This is a handcraft that will naturally become better with time while doing other mathematics, and in the end, it is perhaps not the most important skill. Indeed, this is a task where a computer is often helpful.